# .xlsx cell not being converted to character

Tags: r, excel

I have many .xlsx workbooks and each workbook has multiple sheets. I am attempting to go through all of the sheets in each workbook and change several vales. I am able to change the large numbers (9996, 9997 etc) into the correct values ([x], [u] etc but I can't get the blank/na cells to convert to [x]. Here is my code:

```
right_aligned_style <- createStyle(numFmt = "#,###.0",
                                   halign = "right",
                                   fontSize = 12)

Wblistreplace <- AllWorkbooks$Full_Output[AllWorkbooks$Year == current_year]

for (x in Wblistreplace) {

  new_workbook <- loadWorkbook(paste0(project_root, x, ".xlsx"))

  for (s in 4:length(new_workbook$worksheets)) {
    
    sheet <- new_workbook$worksheets[s] 
    
    values <- sheet[[1]]$sheet_data$v
    values[values == "9999"] <- "[z]"
    values[values == "9998"] <- "[d]"
    values[values == "9997"] <- "[x]"
    values[values == "9996"] <- "[u]"
    values[is.na(values)] <- "[x]"
    
    new_workbook$worksheets[s][[1]]$sheet_data$v <- values
    
    if (AllWorkbooks[which(AllWorkbooks$Full_Output == x), 16] == "No") {

    addStyle(new_workbook, sheet = s,
             style = right_aligned_style,
             rows = 10:(10 + (as.numeric(AllWorkbooks[which(AllWorkbooks$Full_Output == x), 14])) - (as.numeric(AllWorkbooks[which(AllWorkbooks$Full_Output == x), 13]))),
             cols = 3:17,
             gridExpand = TRUE)
    }

    else if (AllWorkbooks[which(AllWorkbooks$Full_Output == x), 16] == "Yes") {

      addStyle(new_workbook, sheet = s,
               style = right_aligned_style,
               rows = 10:(11 + (as.numeric(AllWorkbooks[which(AllWorkbooks$Full_Output == x), 14])) - (as.numeric(AllWorkbooks[which(AllWorkbooks$Full_Output == x), 13]))),
               cols = 3:17,
               gridExpand = TRUE)
    }
    
  }
  
  saveWorkbook(new_workbook,
              paste0(project_root, x, ".xlsx"),
              overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

The line: values[is.na(values)] <- "[x]" does not seem to be working and the cells are still blank after the code has run. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Does `any(is.na(values))` return true? Are you sure they are NA values? Maybe they are just blank values `values[values==""] <- "[x]"`. Hard to say without a reproducible example.

Comment: People will probably be able to figure out you're using `openxlsx`, but it is best to explicitly call `require(openxlsx)` or `library(openxlsx)` in your example code.

Comment: What is the result of `print(values[is.na(values)]`?  If no values are selected, your selection is incorrect.  Otherwise, what values are in those elements of `values` before writing to the revised workbbok?  if that is as expected, then the problem is in writing the revised workbook.  Etc, etc... Without concrete data to work on, all we can do is suggest...

Comment: I can look at the data in 'sheet' and see there are NA values.

Comment: any(is.na(values)) does return TRUE